# Как правильно сверстать первый экран

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, slick.js

Дано: есть первый экран. Он сделан слайдером(slick slider), то есть меняется фон, поверх него есть текст, кнопки, заголовки(bootstrap grid).

Суть вопроса: как правильно сверстать блок. Если делать absolute для текста, кнопок, тогда игнорируется сетка бутстрап. Если делать absolute для слайдера, тогда он после первого круга всех слайдов пропадает и уходит вниз, появляется лишняя прокрутка вниз.

Я выбрал первый вариант, где игнорируется бутстрап, но сайт должен быть адаптивным и при переходе на разрешение меньше это все разваливается и остаётся верстать по брейк поинтам, а не «растягиваемые» блоки, что не есть хорошо. Данное решение считаю не верным, но из-за неопытности исправить ошибку не могу.

Comment: Сделайте блок с текстом через сетку, а вот блок с слайдером разместите абсолютно. Все будет работать если правильно настроить стили и адаптив так же.

Comment: Проблему я уже описал, почему не могу так сделать, не знаю как ее решить.

Comment: Islamov, добавьте пример вашего, так будет проще помочь вам.

Comment: @E_K https://prnt.sc/i9wn4x скрин блока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#js-hero-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  lazyLoad: 'progressive',
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  //adaptiveHeight: true,
  dots: false
});
```

```css
.b-hero {
  height: 60vh;
  position: relative;
}

.l-hero__slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.b-slider__slide {
  height: 60vh !important;
  background-position-x: 50%;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: initial;
  background-origin: initial;
  background-clip: initial;
  background-color: initial;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.4-rc1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Hero -->
<section id="hero" class="b-hero gap l-hero">
  <div class="l-hero__slider">
    <div id="js-hero-slider" class="b-slider b-slider--hero">
      <div class="b-slider__slide" style="background-image: url('http://www.wild-nature.ru/sites/default/files/panorama111_15.jpg')"></div>
      <div class="b-slider__slide" style="background-image: url('http://hitline.org.ua/torrents/images/93983.jpg')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>TEXT</h1>
</section>
<!-- END -->
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я понял принцип решения задачи. Странно что сам к этому не пришел:)